# Alternative skepticism forums

Tags: discussion

In https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14995/if-homeopathy-does-not-work-why-are-there-so-many-shops-selling-the-products , someone asked an interesting question about homeopathy, but not one that's on-topic for this Stack Exchange:

> I gradually got conscious of the fact that there is a huge number of
>   homeopathy shops in London. It is very easy to check, at least using
>   wiki that there exist no scientific evidence that homeopathy works at
>   all. At the same time apparently quite a few people do use it. I
>   wonder if there was some research that explains this phenomena -- why
>   people believe that this can work?
>
> Also I am curious to know if people involved in homeopathy industry
>   really believe in the efficiency of what they are doing?

After explaining why it was off-topic, I was asked for sites which may be more suitable for this question. Unfortunately, I don't know of any good sites, as I'm not involved in the skepticism movement. Does anyone have some good suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

JREF is probably one of the best places.  Skeptics and believers in woo woo debate that topic there (and there is $1,000,000 for a believer if they can provide actual evidence).

Comment: Is the proof assessed by an independent 3rd party? Otherwise I wouldn't submit a proof no matter what it is about.

Comment: Proof is a bad word, I guess evidence is better (I'll edit).  And the demonstration is agreed upon by both parties.  Pass and fail criteria are even know before hand.